# Unable to Hide the Week Column Angular UI Bootsrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Angular JS and I am having trouble with hiding the Week Column in angular UI bootstrap Date picker popup. I changed the value to false in the Angular Js file but the week column doesn't get hidden. below is the link to plunker.

I would also like to know if the styling of the calendar can be changed so that I can split the month and year as 2 separate drop down menu's.

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/IkBBrXxH98DjAwSEhPMe?p=preview)

```
$scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: false
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js)

```
.constant('uibDatepickerConfig', {
datepickerMode: 'day',
formatDay: 'dd',
formatMonth: 'MMMM',
formatYear: 'yyyy',
formatDayHeader: 'EEE',
formatDayTitle: 'MMMM yyyy',
formatMonthTitle: 'yyyy',
maxDate: null,
maxMode: 'year',
minDate: null,
minMode: 'day',
monthColumns: 3,
ngModelOptions: {},
shortcutPropagation: false,
showWeeks: true,   <<---------- SET THIS AS FALSE
yearColumns: 5,
yearRows: 4
})
```

set `showWeeks` as **false**.

You can *right-click* on week number and do **Inspect element** to see how it is getting populated.

For eg:

```
<td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope">
  <em class="ng-binding">38</em>
</td>
```

Here you can see `ng-if` directive which us rendering the week column.

For changing the styles you can either change the existing directive styling or you can find some other custom directive with desired styling. There are plenty of directive, try to google (its a good habit ;) ) and let me know if you cant find one. I'll provide some links then.

**Update 2:**

For making the input field to work on click only, add `readonly` in `input` field.

Something like:

```
 <input type="text"  readonly
            class="form-control" 
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
            ng-model="dt" 
            is-open="popup1.opened" 
            datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
            ng-required="true" close-text="Close" 
            alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
            ng-click="open1()"
            />
```

Comment: Super thanks Shashank. Worked fine. Is there a way to change the style of the calendar like I had asked in the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: Its css styling, either modify existing one or find new one. I suggest you to find new one using google

Comment: Thanks will check.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, I managed to change the css to something different. Also I noticed that I am able to edit the date. How can I disable the editing and just have the date picker popup come up when the user clicks on the input field?

Comment: @prithvi: There you go. Updated the answer. Upvote if it works for you